# looking for feature that will allow me to make repeating if statements easier

Tags: c#, python-3.x

i know this feature exists in c# and have used it but i cant remember what it is called. im trying to find a similar feature in python.
i want to turn this:

```
if option == 1: print("1")
if option == 2: print("2")
if option == 3: print("3")
```

into something like this:

```
if option:
    1: print("1")
    2: print("2")
    3: print("3")
```

i've tried searching the web but it only shows me stuff i'm not looking for

Comment: Welcome to SO, always search before posting a question.  I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: c# - `switch`, Python (3.8 and later) = `match...case`.

Comment: Remove tag `[c#]`. Your question has no relation to it.